# Redirect web page once an internet connection is established

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a web page kiosk for work. When the computer boots, it immediately loads the kiosk, but it takes about a minute to connect to the network. The first thing a user sees is a connection error, because the kiosk tries to visit the live page, but there is no internet yet. The kiosk browser uses **Chrome.**

To prevent the initial error, I am trying to make a locally hosted web page that checks for an internet connection and waits until one is established. Then it redirects to the live page.

Here is the initial offline locally hosted page. It is supposed to redirect from here to the live page. Apparently in Chrome, navigator.onLine only checks if Chrome is set to 'online mode' but doesn't actually test a live connection.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kiosk Splash</title>
  <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="jquery/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css">
  <script src="jquery/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery/js/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog" style="text-align:center;">
    <p>
        <font font face="verdana" size="5">The Kiosk is establishing a connection to the network...</font>
    </p>
    <div id="progressbar" style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto;"></div>
</div>
<script>
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({ minWidth: 1000 });
$(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", this.parentNode).hide();
$( "#progressbar" ).width(800);
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
  value: false
});
while(true){
    if(navigator.onLine){
        window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
        break;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For starters change your `while(true)` to an `interval` as currently this will block the UI from responding.

Comment: Amazing what you find in the [docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.onLine). `window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {alert("online");})` Not fully supported by all browsers. And I think Firefox has an issue saying you are always online. ;)

Comment: @epascarello I should have mentioned that I tried that as well and got the same result: it fires the online immediately, even before theres a connection. I'm wondering if 'online' just detects if the browser is set to 'online' mode.

Comment: Depends on the browser, what one are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of `navigator.onLine` how it works.
 but it should try to connect to server and keep trying till it get connected to server. after connection redirect

```
      function connect(){
      try{
        $.ajax({url:"http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=metallica", // any url which return json
        success: function(){
        location.href = "http://google.com"  
     },
     error: function(e){
         location.href = "http://google.com";
     }, 
       dataType:"json"
   });
}catch(e){
     console.log(e);         
    setTimeout(connect, 5000);
}
} 
connect();
```

Comment: Did you test if this works? It's not working for me (also you were missing a bracket to close {url} but it still doesn't work with that)

Comment: Yes I tested it and it is working now. problem was cross domain access restriction.

Comment: You nytimes example URL wasn't working, but I was able to make your code work using http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=metallica as the test url. I'm hesitant to accept this an answer though, because if the hard-coded URL is down or changes, the code for this web page will break.

Comment: I know, you should provide url of your server. that way you can have control.

Comment: Okay, so this solution doesn't work (at least not with Chrome). When the browser initially loads (before an internet connection is established) it only tries once to make the AJAX call and returns "Failed to load resource" in the javascript console. It works if you reload the page once the connection is up.

Comment: No it is not working, it gives the exact same error as before. I don't think you're testing these solutions at all before posting them.

Answer (score 0):

If navigator.online is not working let's do this manually.

A possibility is to check the connection by seeing if you can ping your server.  To do this set up an ajax call that tries to retrieve data.  If it comes back successful, then you are connected!  Then you can redirect to the new page.

```
$(function() {
  var myVar=setInterval(function(){ pingServer(); }, 1000),
      urlOnServer = "http://www.google.com",
      urlOfHomePage = "http://www.yahoo.com";

  function pingServer() {
    $.ajax({
      url: urlOnServer,
      data: null,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
        window.location = urlOfHomePage;
      }
    });
  } 
});
```

Comment: I made an edit to hopefully help you get it working.  Hope that helps! ps. Those urls need to change.  You have to set up a method on your back end code that will handle an ajax call.